# Google jib - Change owner of all files and folders

Tags: jib, maven-jib

All the app files and extraDirectories are owned by root.

```
/app/libs/
/app/resources/ 
/app/classes/
/app/logs
```

I want to run the application as non-root user and i want these files/folders to be owned by that user only and not root.

Is there any way to do this ? I found below mentioned jib maven plugin to alter the owner but it recommends not to do it. Is there any better way ?

https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib-extensions/tree/master/first-party/jib-ownership-extension-maven

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you want to change the ownership of some part of the app directory is that your app wants to modify some files or create new ones inside it at runtime. Generally speaking, it is considered a good practice to build an image to be immutable as much as possible.

Since you mentioned `/app/logs`, I suspect that your app generates log files while it is running. On some modern container orchestration platforms (such as Kubernetes), apps are usually designed to [output logs to `stdout` and `stderr`](https://logz.io/blog/a-practical-guide-to-kubernetes-logging/).

> The best practice is to write your application logs to the standard output (`stdout`) and standard error (`stderr`) streams.

Think about it: if your app generates logs files at `/app/logs` inside a container (there will be multiple containers of the same image running), how would you collect and monitor them in a unified way? What if different apps generate log files at different file system locations? But more importantly, if your container crashes, you'll just lose the log files. By writing logs to `stdout` and `stderr`, the platform (say, Kubernetes) will take care of all the complexities of managing and co-relating logs from all pods.

If you cannot change your app about the log files, at least you should mount a volume at `/app/logs` at runtime. For any container runtime (be it k8s or Docker), this is easily configurable. The mounted directory will be usually world-writable, so you won't need to change the ownership. But you'll still have to think about how to collect and manage the log files.

Likewise, if it is not for log files but that your app needs a file system to create a temporary file inside the app directory and you cannot change the location for some reason, at least you should try to mount an ephemeral volume before falling back to the last-resort of using the Jib Ownership Extension you mentioned.

Conclusively, give a careful assessment of why you have to change the ownership first. If the app wants to mutate itself at runtime, usually it's not a good practice for containerization and there must be some root cause that you may need to resolve in a proper way.

Comment: I have a scenario where it would be helpful if I could change ownership of a directory or file to a user: we use a script to format the environment variables from JSON to env vars.  This script creates a file in the /home/api-runtime directory (working directory).  Because the directory is owned by root, it gets permission denied when trying to create the file.  As a workaround, I'm copying an empty file and setting permission to 777 for it and it is working fine.  I would have liked for JIB to set the owner of the workingDirectory to my user (1001) and not root.